# Difficulty in inner-joining two tables in R with some mutations

Tags: r, inner-join

I am struggling to join two tables in R:

1. The first table is called lsr_df and it has the shape as below. It is composed of pair of stocks and specific dates in addition to other columns.

   ```
   dput(head(lsr_df,10))
   ```

   structure(list(stock1 = c("FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", 
   "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR"), stock2 = c("PLD", "LMP.L", "WKP.L", 
   "OLP", "GOOD", "RES.JO", "UKCM.L", "GRT.JO", "ROIC", "O5RU.SI"
   ), startofyear = structure(c(14610, 14610, 14610, 14610, 14610, 
   14610, 14610, 14610, 14610, 14610), class = "Date"), lb20mean = 
   c(-0.0693048515541775, 
   -0.0781003327926435, 0.0270008111538754, -0.029754549133328, 
   -0.12510116675199, -0.0871014558625667, 16.8576182871088, 
   -0.0845322274926097, 
   -0.113270435178336, -0.0373054503504677), lb20stdev = 
   c(0.194245073984498, 
   0.238650622720019, 0.241026669919644, 0.252345490511642, 
   0.20920635975478, 
   0.258911498912729, 5.49626511810755, 0.260155498292147, 
   0.211708554064302, 
   0.312881208877686)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
   "tbl", "data.frame"))
2. The second table is called liquidity_df. It is composed of each stock liquidity profile on specific dates.

   dput(head(liquidity_df,10))
   structure(list(ticker = c("0004.HK", "0004.HK", "0004.HK", 
   "0004.HK", 
   "0004.HK", "0004.HK", "0004.HK", "0004.HK", "0004.HK", "0004.HK"
   ), year = structure(c(11688, 12053, 12418, 12784, 13149, 13514, 
   13879, 15706, 16071, 16436), class = "Date"), isLiquid = c(0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = 
   structure(list(
   ticker = "0004.HK", .rows = list(1:10)), row.names = c(NA, 
   -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class 
   = c("grouped_df", 
   "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
3. I would like to create a new table that will be the result of the inner-join of lsr_df with an additional column taken from liquidity_df table.This new column is called liquid and indicates the liquidity profile of each pair of stocks in lsr_df. See that the lsr_df table has pair of stocks and the liquidity table has one stock per row. Therefore the code should look for each row of stock pairs in lsr_df, get the isLiquid value for each stock in the pair in each date (in the liquidity_df table) and check if it attends the condition == 1 for both stocks, and return 1, else return 0 in the newly created lsrf_df table column liquid.

I tried the code below:

````
lsrf_df <- lsr_df %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  inner_join(liquidity_df, by = c('stock1' = 'ticker')) %>%
  inner_join(liquidity_df, by = c('stock2' = 'ticker')) %>%                                
  mutate(liquid = case_when(isLiquid.x == 1 & isLiquid.y == 1 ~ 
  as.integer(1), TRUE ~ as.integer(0)))
```
The code above creates new and different date columns (see below) instead of using the lsr_df dates. The result I would like is to just add the new liquid column with the correct value (condition) for each original pair and date.



    stock1 stock2 startofyear lb20mean lb20stdev year.x     isLiquid.x 
    year.y     isLiquid.y liquid   <chr>  <chr>  <date>         <dbl>     
    <dbl> <date>          <dbl> <date>          <dbl>  <int> 1 FR     
    PLD  2010-01-01   -0.0693     0.194 2000-01-01          0 2000-01-01        
    0      0 2 FR     PLD    2010-01-01   -0.0693     0.194 2000-01-01     
    0 2001-01-01          0      0 3 FR     PLD    2010-01-01   -0.0693   
    0.194 2000-01-01          0 2002-01-01          0      0 4 FR     
    PLD    2010-01-01   -0.0693     0.194 2000-01-01          0 2003-01- 
    01        0      0 5 FR     PLD    2010-01-01   -0.0693     0.194 
    2000-01-01     0 2004-01-01          0      0 6 FR     PLD    2010- 
    01-01   -0.0693   
    0.194 2000-01-01          0 2005-01-01          0      0
````

Comment: Please do not provide data as an image.  No one wants to type it all in again. instead use `dput` e.g. `dput(head(lsrf_df, 10))` and paste the results into your question.  You might also read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Also, please do a minimal working example, i.e. provide the parts of the pipe that produce the error - the `group_by()` at the end for example doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Georgery thank, I am new here, I think now I did the changes you asked for

Comment: @G5W thanks, I edit the post with the modifications you asked

Comment: Hey @FMF, so the problem with the data is that your join-columns don't have any rows in common and therefore should not return any rows at all when using an inner-join. Do you generally know how joins work?

Comment: @Georgery the tables should join by the date column of each one (year and startofyear) and by ticker. The lsr_df table has pairs of tickers, the liquidity-df has one  at each row that should match the pairs of the former table. Example: table lsr_df stockA stockB 2000-01-01, table liquidity stockA in row1, stockB in row2, 2000-01-01, 2000-01-01. If stockA and stockB in the liquidity_df have both value 1, a new column in lsr_df called liquid is filled with 1 for the stockA/stockB pair.